# Sklearn Label Encoder Inverse Transform with Surprise Predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorization

I have a dataset that I am using Label Encoder to categorize my data (from strings into numbers).

Then I am using the Surprise library to train a Recommendation System model.

I get the predictions using the following code:

```
# A reader is still needed but only the rating_scale param is requiered.
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(1, 100))

# The columns must correspond to user id, item id and ratings (in that order).
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df_categorized, reader)

# First train an SVD algorithm on the dataset.
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
algo = SVD()
algo.fit(trainset)

# Than predict ratings for all pairs (u, i) that are NOT in the training set.
testset = trainset.build_anti_testset()
predictions = algo.test(testset)

top_n = get_top_n(predictions, n=5)
```

I used a top_n method that gets the top_n recommendations as follows:

```
def get_top_n(predictions, n=5):
    '''Return the top-N recommendation for each user from a set of predictions.

    Args:
        predictions(list of Prediction objects): The list of predictions, as
            returned by the test method of an algorithm.
        n(int): The number of recommendation to output for each user. Default
            is 10.

    Returns:
    A dict where keys are user (raw) ids and values are lists of tuples:
        [(raw item id, rating estimation), ...] of size n.
    '''

    # First map the predictions to each user.
    top_n = defaultdict(list)
    for uid, iid, true_r, est, _ in predictions:
        top_n[uid].append((iid, est))

    # Then sort the predictions for each user and retrieve the k highest ones.
    for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
        user_ratings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        top_n[uid] = user_ratings[:n]

    return top_n
```

Since the data was first categorized using the Label Encoder, the top_n refers to the userId as encoded values, and the recommended content as encoded values as well.

How do I inverse transform the data back into unencoded values?

I have tried to get the keys returned from top_n (userId encoded) and use the label encoders inverse transform method, however, since it is in a dict, it doesn't have the indexing required for the method to work. The same goes for the recommended content that is stored as the values in the dict.

Comment: Can you share your output

Comment: @VivekKumar, {userIdCategorized: [contentIdCategorized...], ...} is the form of the output where the keys are is the encoded versions of userId and the values are a list of recommended contentIdcategorized.